# Well-definedness of Guillemin and Pollack's $df_x$

Tags: differential-topology

In Guillemin and Pollack, given a smooth map $f:X\to Y$ on smooth manifolds, parametrizations $\phi:U\to X$ and $\psi:V\to Y$ in the commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ll}
X & \overset{f}{\to} &Y\\
\uparrow\phi & & \uparrow\psi\\
U & \overset{h}{\to}& V
\end{array}$$
with $h=\psi^{-1}\circ f\circ\phi$, he defines $df_x=d\psi_0\circ dh_0\circ (d\phi_0)^{-1}$ (where the operation $d(-)_{pt}$ is the usual jacobian matrix computed at a specific point for a function defined on an open subset of euclidean space) and it is left to the reader to check that this generalization is well-defined. Well, as it happens, I am currently the reader and I haven't been able to show it. My hang up is that I need the following to hold for these local parametrizations:
$$(d\phi_0)^{-1}=d(\phi^{-1})_x$$
however, the term on the right hand side is one of the objects that we are currently trying to show is indeed well-defined (since $\phi^{-1}:\text{im}(\phi(U))\to U$ is not defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$). However, the smooth extension of $\phi^{-1}$, which I guess we can call $\Phi^{-1}$, has the following property: $$d(\Phi^{-1})_x\circ i_{T_x(X)}=(d\phi_0)^{-1}$$
which, later on, gives what we want since the chain rule would imply that 
$$d(\Phi^{-1})_x\circ i_{T_x(X)}=d(\Phi^{-1}\circ i_{X})_x=d(\phi^{-1})_x$$ (where $i_X$ is the inclusion of $X$ into the domain of $\Phi^{-1}$)

I've spent longer than I'd like to admit on this, and every set of lecture notes I turn to seems to exclude this demonstration (which I sympathize with). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MathStackExchange is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: The question is also posted there, no one seems interested in answering it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472643/well-definedness-of-derivative-of-smooth-map-between-smooth-manifolds . No answer since October 2017 :-( . I can understand why the question was posted here.